# How to use same function in multiple buttons to get same result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create onlick function in multiple ids, it works in one id but doesn't work in others. I know someone will suggest me to different onclick function along with separate ids but I want to use only the one onclick function with same ids in all div elements.

I want somebody to create Javascript with a single function and single ids for getting the same result in all three buttons.

Just check my codes below;

```js
function copy() {
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <p id="label">Mouse over me</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick="copy();">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="dropdown">
    <p id="label">Mouse over me</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick="copy();">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <p id="label">Mouse over me</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick="copy();">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to use jquery function in this case? If yes then what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could target the right elements from the actual section using `.closest()`, e.g.

```
<button onClick="copy(this);">Add</button>
```

and

```
function copy(el) {
  var dd = el.closest('.dropdown');
  dd.querySelector('p').innerHTML =  dd.querySelector('select').value;
}
```

---

```js
var copy = function(el) {
  var dd = el.closest('.dropdown');
  dd.querySelector('p').innerHTML =  dd.querySelector('select').value;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <p id="label">Mouse over me</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick="copy(this);">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <p id="label">Mouse over me</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick="copy(this);">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>
```